# Create a url link with an ID for an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

In my view page, I want to link to the action "Display" and pass it the ID that the action expects as a parameter.

Which html helper do I use?  I don't want it to create the a href page of the string, just the url.

Answer (score 2):

`<%= Url.Action("Display", "controller", new {ID = someIdValue}); %>`